# Adding additional column to an INNER JOIN SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have the following INNER JOIN query which you can see in action in a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af131/1).

```
SELECT  b.*, c.date2
FROM    (
            SELECT a.work, a.amount, 
                   COUNT(*) totalCount, 
                   SUM(Amount) totalAmount
            FROM tableName a
            GROUP BY a.work, a.amount
        ) b
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT a.work, a.amount, DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%D %M %Y') date2,
                    date
            FROM tableName a
        ) c ON b.work = c.work and b.amount=c.amount
ORDER BY b.work, b.totalCount, c.date
```

I would like to add a further column, called 'url' to the query, which works in the same way as the date column, i.e. it returns the distinct value in the 'url' column for each row. You can find the schema that includes the new column in a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af131/15).  I am not sure how to adapt the query to return an extra column with the distinct 'url' values.  I have tried a few things, but can't get it working right.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The expect output is the same as in the first fiddle, but with an additional column for the distinct URL values for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this...

```
    SELECT  b.*, c.date2, c.url
    FROM    (
            SELECT a.work, a.amount, 
                   COUNT(*) totalCount, 
                   SUM(Amount) totalAmount
            FROM tableName a
            GROUP BY a.work, a.amount
        ) b
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT a.work, a.amount, DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%D %M %Y') date2,
                    date, url
            FROM tableName a
        ) c ON b.work = c.work and b.amount=c.amount
    ORDER BY b.work, b.totalCount, c.date
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine.  I'm sure I tried that solution, but it would seem that I couldn't have!

Answer (score 2):

It can be written in shorter like

```
 SELECT a.work, a.amount, 
                   COUNT(*) totalCount, 
                   SUM(Amount) totalAmount, url, DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%D %M %Y')
            FROM tableName a
            GROUP BY a.work, a.amount, DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%D %M %Y')
```